# Expanding one accordion item in the view

Tags: javascript, templates, height, accordion, webix

I have a form and onlu one accordion item within in (to show an additional information about other content).
But seems like one accordion item don't want to collapse/expand properly. If I set `collapsed:false`, it cannot be collapsed at all. If `collapsed:true`, it can be expanded only once and then never collapsed.

I suspect the problem is in the filling a determined height, but I can't solve it by myself.

What have I done wrong?

Here's a short code preview:

```
view:"form",
elements:[    
    { height:300 },
    {
      view:"accordion",           
      rows:[                  
        {
          view:"accordionitem",           
          height:150,
          collapsed:true, 
          body:{
            template:""
          }                         
        }        
      ]
    },
    { autoheight:true }
]
```

[**Full snippet**](http://webix.com/snippet/61613329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, accordion ensure that at least one panel is always visible. 
You can add `multi:true` to the accordion's config, to disable this behavior.

```
  {
    view:"accordion", multi:true,            
    rows:[                  
      {
        height:150,
        collapsed:true,  
        header:"test",
        body:{
          template:""
        }                         
      }        
    ]
  },
```

http://webix.com/snippet/cff77257

Answer (score 1):

Hey i did some workarounds in the structure. Please check the code in the image and it works fine with the accordion as you required.[Restructured Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4ynV.jpg)

Comment: Yep, I see. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I think the nature of Accordian control is to always show at least one item. So you are forcing it do something which is not designed to do so.

Why don't you use something like jquery hide/show to display extra info?